# Inserting element in one list based on another list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two list of list `sigma, Cb_max1`. I want to insert `0.021` in `sigma` corresponding to every non-zero element in `Cb_max1`. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
sigma = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.005, 0]]
Cb_max1 = [[0.0009847628716281426, 0.0009847628716281426, 0, 0, 0, 0.0009800221856714917, 0]]
sigma = [i if j != 0 else 0.021 for i, j in zip(Cb_max1, sigma[0])]
print(sigma)
```

The current output is

```
[0.021]
```

The expected output is

```
[[0.021, 0.021, 0, 0, 0, 0.005, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sigma = [[(0.021 if i != 0 else 0) if j == 0 else j 
          for (i, j) in zip(Cb_max1[0], sigma[0])]]

print(sigma)
```

---

```
[[0.021, 0.021, 0, 0, 0, 0.005, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating a list of length 1 as `zip` stops as soon as the shorter iterator stops. You might want to iterate the inner lists:

```
sigma = [i if j != 0 else 0.021 for i, j in zip(Cb_max1[0], sigma[0])]
```

If you want `sigma` to be a nested list you need to add an extra couple of brackets:

```
sigma = [[i if j != 0 else 0.021 for i, j in zip(Cb_max1[0], sigma[0])]]
```

Also you are checking the values of `sigma` and you say you want to check the values of `Cb_max`:

```
sigma = [[j if i != 0 else 0.021 for i, j in zip(Cb_max1[0], sigma[0])]]
```

And you wrote the condition in the opposite way:

```
sigma = [[j if i == 0 else 0.021 for i, j in zip(Cb_max1[0], sigma[0])]]
```

This satisfies the description you provided.
You gave an output that does not seem to correspond with this.
Maybe you want to satisfy other condition: you want to keep the non zero values in `sigma[0]`:

```
sigma = [[(j if i == 0 else 0.021)
          if j == 0 else j
          for i, j in zip(Cb_max1[0], sigma[0])]]
```

Finally this will give you the expected output.

If you prefer to write it in a more simple way:

```
sigma = [[0.021 if j == 0 and i != 0 else j
          for i, j in zip(Cb_max1[0], sigma[0])]]
```

Comment: I don't get the expected output.